# Eclipse not running anymore - code 13

Tags: java, eclipse

I updated my java "jre" and during the installation, the wizard asked me to uninstall earlier versions as a safety measure, so i did.
I have java version 1.8 now but when i run eclipse i get "code 13" error, saying that it requires version 1.6. Is there a solution to this problem other than uninstalling eclipse and re-installing it? I have plenty of plugins going on there with emulators for android.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: what version of Eclipse you are using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse luna.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Eclipse.ini file, whether the path to javaa is provided correct.

eg:

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
```

The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
The value must be the full absolute path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.
The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM

Comment: _-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
_

Comment: it seems there is no -vm option in your eclipse.ini file

Comment: You don't have to have a -vm entry in the eclipse.ini, the default Java is used if there is no entry.

Comment: Find the Java 8 java.exe and run "java.exe -d64" with it so see if it's 64-bit capable. The version of Eclipse you have requires a 64-bit JRE, and error 13 would seem to indicate you have a 32-bit version (or some other issue with that JRE).

Comment: I am adding the -vm + path in the eclipse.ini, but it is giving me another error "no Java virtual machine can be found in the following..." should i uninstall eclipse ?